# Crear una ColeccionUsuarios y que este relacionada con Medico y Administrador con mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

Buenas mi problema es el siguiente, quiero realizar un login a una pagina y claro tengo 2 colecciones y mi idea seria crear una tercera colección que seria usuarios y ahí podría realizar el login pero claro el problema es el siguiente

Esta 3ª coleccion tendria que relacionarse con lo que contiene la primera y segunda coleccion osease Medicos y Administradores

Este es el modelo de medico

```
const { Schema, model, SchemaType } = require('mongoose');
const hospital = require('./hospital');
const rol = require('./rol');
const { collection } = require('./administrador');

const MedicoSchema = Schema({

    nombre: {
        type: String,
        require: true

    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },

    img: {
        type: String,
    },
    administrador: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Administrador',
        required: true
    },
    hospital: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Hospital',
        required: true
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: '2',
    }

});

MedicoSchema.method('toJSON', function () {

    const { __v, ...object } = this.toObject();

    return object;
})

module.exports = model('Medico', MedicoSchema);
```

Y este es el modelo de Administrador

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const AdministradorSchema = Schema({

    nombre: {
        type: String,
        require: true

    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    img: {
        type: String,
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        default: '1',
    },
    google: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false

    },
}, { collection: 'administradores' });

AdministradorSchema.method('toJSON', function () {

    const { __v, _id, password, ...object } = this.toObject();

    object.uid = _id;

    return object;
})

module.exports = model('Administrador', AdministradorSchema);
```

Lo que no consigo es crear una tabla usuarios donde este relacionada con estas dos tablas donde me contenga todos los datos de estas dos tablas para que en el controlador del login que es así pueda recorrerlo y hacer la autorización para la pagina. Este es el controlador que uso ahora para que solo me lea la tabla administradores para acceder

```
const { response } = require('express');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const Administrador = require('../models/administrador');
const Medico = require('../models/medico');
const { generarJWT } = require('../helpers/jwt');

const login = async (req, res = response) => {


    const { email, password } = req.body;


    try {
        //Verificar Email
        const administradorDB = await Administrador.findOne({ email });

        if (!administradorDB) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                ok: false,
                msg: 'Email no valido'
            });
        }
        //verificar Constraseña
        const validPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(password, administradorDB.password);

        if (!validPassword) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                ok: false,
                msg: 'Contraseña no Valida'
            });
        }


        //Generar el TOKEN - JWT
        const token = await generarJWT(administradorDB.id);

        res.json({
            ok: true,
            msg: 'Logaste como Administrador',
            token
        })


    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({
            ok: false,
            msg: 'Error al Loguear'
        })
    }

}


const googleSingIn = async (req, res = response) => {

    res.json({
        ok: true,
        msg: req.body.token
    });

}
//Renovar Token
const renewToken = async (req, res = response) => {

    const uid = req.uid;

    //Generar el Token -JWT
    const token = await generarJWT(uid);

    //Obtener el administrador por UID
    const administrador = await Administrador.findById(uid);
    res.json({
        ok: true,
        token,
        administrador
    })

}

module.exports = {
    login,
    googleSingIn,
    renewToken
}
```

Por favor como podría hacerlos relacionales porque no soy capaz de discurrirlo gracias a todos de ante mano

Comment: Primero: no existen tablas en MongoDB, son colecciones. Segundo: los documentos entre colecciones no se relacionan, se crean referencias (no es lo mismo). No mezcles los conceptos SQL con noSQL, ya que te puede conducir a errores y te hará difícil encontrar la solución al problema. Por otro lado, la documentación de Mongoose es bastante explícita sobre tu caso de uso. De igual manera, la documentación de MongoDB dispone de ejemplos que darían una idea de cómo resolverlo. Saludos

Comment: Entonces lo plantee todo mal desde el principio revise despues de leer tu respuesta y encontre el populate probare a usarlo a ver si consigo hacer la relacion entre las 2 colecciones muchas gracias